# Why is one of the lines the wrong color?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Running this through the debugger shows that the first line is drawn blue.
The second line is drawn red but the blue line gets drawn over with red.
Apologies if it's something obvious but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let line1 = {
  P1: {
    x: 90,
    y: 50
  },
  P2: {
    x: 110,
    y: 10
  },
  color: "blue",
};
let line2 = {
  P1: {
    x: 10,
    y: 150
  },
  P2: {
    x: 80,
    y: 130
  },
  color: "red",
};

drawLines(line1);
drawLines(line2);


function drawLines(line) {

  ctx.strokeStyle = line.color;
  ctx.moveTo(line.P1.x, line.P1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(line.P2.x, line.P2.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Start `drawLines` function with line `ctx.beginPath();` to apply the colors correctly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath

Comment: Thanks very much, you saved me several more hours trying to figure that out!